# List of UWP DeviceFamliy values is where?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Is there a spot to get the full official range of DeviceFamily possible values as used in - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx .  Darned if I can't find it.  Thanks...

Comment: New device families can be added in the future (indeed, Holographic showed up recently), so programs shouldn't assume that they have the complete list.

Comment: Hi Joe. Unfortunately currently there is no such list. For sure It will be extended in the nearest future. For now there are stable families like Mobile, Desktop or Universal.

Comment: @Raymond, anything partial past the list I pasted.  love your uwp samples!